.htaccess URL Rewrite Rule Not Working In Subdirectory of Existing WordPress Site on Apache
I am trying to get a redirect rule working in a subfolder so I can rewrite a URL from:
https://www.somesite.co.uk/api/FormEntries.php?id=1

To (which is how users would access the above to provide a more friendly URL):
https://www.somesite.co.uk/api/FormEntries/1

Where:

Name of php file is the first variable so could have /api/OtherObject/1
Number on end is the Id of the record

This is the content of the .htaccess file where I only want to affect this sub-folder.
When using online testers they seem to suggest the rule works until I add the RewriteBase value but I have tried adding the main rewrite rule to the top level .htaccess too as the first rule with an [L] tag on the end but I still cannot get it to work. Rewrite works in general on the server so I don't think it is a hosting issue but not sure if WordPress is causing any other conflict in the parent folder.
These are the contents of the .htaccess file:
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /api/
RewriteRule ^api/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/?([0-9]+)?$ /api/$1.php?id=$2 [NC,QSA,L]

Thanks
Robin

That rule should work and testers confirm that. So there has to be some other reason why you say this does not work. What is your actual issue, so the faulty result you see?

Besides: what sense is there in the NC flag if you use a matching pattern including lower and upper case characters?

The solution is to remove the RewriteBase /api/.

@arkascha The issue is that if I go to that URL I get a 404 Not Found error so it isn't working and if I try it without the RewriteBase command then it still doesn't work. If I only want to apply it to this folder I thought it was perhaps safer to add this command but isn't working with or without that. I was just trying all flags on and off to see if it made a difference.

I have finally managed to fix it and this combination is working with the `.htaccess' file in the subfolder:
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
DirectoryIndex FormEntries.php

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /api/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/?([0-9]+)?$ /api/$1.php?id=$2 [NC,QSA,L]

So now /api/FormEntries/1 goes to /api/FormEntries.php?id=1 successfully showing the output from the API in a more user friendly way.
I have left in the flags as NC is useful for not being case sensitive so it will still work if all lowercase, QSA is useful to pass on any additional query parameters that are added and L to avoid processing other rules if this one matches so all seems to be doing what I had hoped it would do.

If the .htaccess file is at the root of the api directory, you don't want to reference it again in your rules or it will try to find a api directory inside api directory, which is not the case and obviously leads to a 404 page.
So this one line htaccess inside api directory will work as I tested in a WordPress with your file structure in the below comment.
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)                 $1.php?id=$2 [QSA,L]


This is not really an answer. The OPs rule actually follows that pattern, but "does not work" according to what is claimed. So this does not help at all.

@arkascha OP's rule in htaccess tester returns the same url as output, wich obviously will give a 404 error ( https://example.com/api/FormEntries/1 ). With the simple rule in my answer the output url for https://example.com/api/FormEntries/1 is https://example.com/api/FormEntries.php?id=1 which is I assume the desired behaviour to use the correct php file with the correct id

You are wrong. The rule the OP uses works perfectly well. Take a look yourself: https://htaccess.madewithlove.com?share=8cf8e8df-f380-4fe1-bad5-d1aa11369e21 The issue is not the rule, it is the RewriteBase he is using. Once more: the rule you posted does more or less the same as the OPs rule, only that it is much more generic (which is not what the OP asked for).

And ... just by the way ... not sure where you copied that from, but that "" in your rule does not make much sense ...

@gael Thanks for providing another option but for whatever reason this one does not work either (i.e. I only added your 2 lines into the .htaccess file). So rewriting is working in general as there is a WordPress site with its default .htaccess file in the root folder and the Apache website uses rewrite to redirect http to https but I just don't get why this won't work when it does in the online testers and seems like quite a simple rule. Perhaps something else is interfering with it but I'm just not sure what.

@RobinWilson, is the api directory a sub directory in a WordPress? What would be the file structure?

The folder structure is api, wp-admin, wp-content, wp-includes with the WordPress index.php and .htaccess in the root folder. I have just managed to get it working and posted the code in an answer.
